# Function for onMouseEnter is not being consistent, occasionally not reading element Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to `add an onMouseEnter function and an onMouseLeave function` to a div element in React. The functions work most of the time but for some reason, sometimes I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

The component that is receiving the functions:

```
const Content = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6" 
             id="1" 
             onMouseEnter={props.handleHover}
             onMouseLeave={props.handleLeave}
        >
          <p>Content<p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6" 
               id="2" 
               onMouseEnter={props.handleHover}
               onMouseLeave={props.handleLeave}
          >
            <p>Content<p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 export default Content
```

And my main component with the functions, this is where I'm getting the error, when I try and declare the id variable, sometimes it says that

> event.target.attributes.id.value is undefined

```
class Projects extends React.Component {
    state = {
        // n.a.
    }

    handleHover = event => {
        const id = event.target.attributes.id.value
        const div = document.getElementById(id)
        // do something
    }

    handleLeave = event => {
        const id = event.target.attributes.id.value
        const div = document.getElementById(id)
        // do something
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="projects-div">
                <Content 
                    handleHover={this.handleHover}
                    handleLeave={this.handleLeave}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Projects
```

Here is a runnable sample with React removed from the mix:

```js
const handleHover = event => {
    const id = event.target.attributes.id.value
    const div = document.getElementById(id)
    console.log({action: "hover", id, div})
    //console.log(id)
    // do something
}

const handleLeave = event => {
    const id = event.target.attributes.id.value
    const div = document.getElementById(id)
    console.log({action: "leave", id, div})
    // do something
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-6" id="1" onMouseEnter="handleHover(event)" onMouseLeave="handleLeave(event)">
      <p>Content
        <p>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-6" id="2" onMouseEnter="handleHover(event)" onMouseLeave="handleLeave(event)">
      <p>Content
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the event being triggered by mouseenter on the nested <p> element which is bubbling up? Try setting an different id on those, or look at the event target in your console or debugger.

Comment: What is the `Content` inside your `<p>Content</p>`?

Comment: @varontron Yeah I think thats what is causing the problem. I tried adding an idea to the <p> element and i'm not getting any errors for the onMouseEnter but I'm still getting them onMouseLeave function

Comment: @BlueWater86 just some text

Comment: if you test for `event.target` and get anything nested, you can you `Element.closest('.md-col-6')` or similar call to get the id of the desired parent [MDN Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: I edited your question so that it was runnable without React. You are hitting a DOM event propagation issue; not an issue with React. I expect that there is more markup on your page (not shown in your question) causing the issue.

Comment: I ended up not using any of these handlers and instead did everything with pure css,  turned out to be a lot simpler that way. Thank you all for the help thought, much appreciated